# GoogleApiClient hangs forever with no callback

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-fit

This is getting me mad.
I have a client trying to connect to Google Fit API in an Android app.
The client was already authorised before (and that step works).

Here's the call:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity.getApplicationContext())
            .addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    LogExt.i(MyClass.class, "Connected to Google Fit....");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    LogExt.d(MyClass.class, "Connection to Google APIs suspended");
                }
            });
        builder.enableAutoManage(PinCodeActivity.instance, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                if (connectionResult.isSuccess()) {
                    LogExt.i(MyClass.class, "Connected to Google Fit !");
                } else {
                    LogExt.e(MyClass.class, "Cannot connect Google Fit: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    gclient = builder.build();
    LogExt.d(MyClass.class, "Going to connect to Google APIs...");
    gclient.connect();
```

The app then does nothing. No logs printed. No connections. No disconnections. Nothing at all.
I have looked at the general log and still can't find any clue.

Run on Samsung Galaxy S6, android 6.0.1, imported libraries: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.4.0`

I'm lost. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It had to do with the activity that was passed to the enableAutoManage(). The activity that was passed was then destroyed, so the client got lost somewhere.

It's a pity that the client has to be bound to an activity, because one cannot go through different activities with the same client, but that's the way it is. It's also a pity that there is no feedback one could rely on to debug this.